# "Huge class files are bad" — is it really and what is the best solution?

Tags: oop

In a code review, I heard it is bad to create huge classes with a lot lines of code. Apparently the 1000 rules of code I had was terrible practice in terms of readability/navigability, I do hear some sense in that.

So I have some complex classes which are basically the code logic behind different screens. I'm programming on Android so this is for example for a Fragment or Activity (though this is a generic question).

Now I can choose to group methods and put them in Utility classes. This will at the very least shorten my code in the sense of lines per class and put some feeling about what method is where. The methods though, are really only used by no more than 1 class, so should this really be a utility class? My gut feeling says utility classes should be stateless classes that contain static methods usable for classes.

Now I could also go for collapsible code blocks and group my methods in them. This will provide readability and usability for me, but not for other programmers.

Then if I look at for instance the Android Activity class, it contains over 6000 lines of code. Is this considered bad practice as well?

I realize this question might be too much "opinion based" but I hope there is a clear and common answer to it.

Comment: Huge amount of lines is a sign of a bad design. You don't want to navigate in a 6000 lines code.

Answer (score 3):

Lines of code is a somewhat meaningless measure in my opinion. Certain types of classes are going to be naturally longer - for example MVC controllers.

The most important principal to keep in mind when designing a class is the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which states:

> every class should have a single responsibility, and that
>   responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class

The Activity type in Android *could* well follow this principal and still be 6000 lines long if, for example, an activity is a very complex thing which requires lots of horrible nested control and flow statements.

Without seeing the class it's difficult to say, however, in practice, it's unlikely that a well designed single class would grow to this size.